# More robust measure than Mean

Tags: estimation, mean, robust

I am currently dealing with data with many outliers and I shall not to eliminate them from the data for analytical purposes. What measure shall I use to describe central tendency of the data yet with a less sensitive measure than the mean?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency?

Answer (score 1):

Median, subsample mean, RPCA, any robust statistic operator...

Answer (score 1):

The median is a smart choice here since it is pretty robust against outliers. It represents the value which splits the data between the lower half and the higher half - it can be read as the 50% percentile.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median